# If $ u+v+w=0 ||u||=5 ||v||=6 ||w||=7$ find $u.v$

Tags: vectors

I would ask for some tips but I don't even know where to start!

If

$ u+v+w=0  \\ ||u||=5 \\ ||v||=6  \\ ||w||=7$

find $u.v$

Comment: Set $x = u + v$ in the identity $||x||^2 = x \cdot x$.

Comment: You may use the law of cosine as well.  (It's just a different disguise.)

Comment: Result is equal to 6?

Comment: Am I the only one seeing a zero there? Wouldn't that imply $u=v=w=0?$

Comment: @Bemte they're (linearly dependent) vectors.

Answer (score 1):

We have $w=-(u+v)$ hence

$49=||w||^2=||u+v||^2=||u||^2+2u.v+||v||^2$.

Your turn

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a triangle $ABC$ such that $|AB|=5,|BC|=6, |CA|=7$. Then we can take $\vec{u}=\vec{AB}, \vec{v}=\vec{BC},\vec{w}=\vec{CA}$ and therefore $$\vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w}=\vec{0}$$ satisfy. By cosine theorem $$\cos (ABC)=\dfrac{5^2+6^2-7^2}{2\cdot5\cdot6}=\dfrac{1}5$$ Hence, cosine of the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ will be $-\dfrac15$. Thus,

$$\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}=5\cdot 6 \cdot (-\dfrac15)=-6$$